# Can you create a linked server from SQL Server to DB2 using JDBC?

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, db2

I'm trying to create a linked server in Sql Server 2014 to a vendors DB2 database which is on a remote system.  I have found a lot of good instructions for doing this but have been not having luck getting that to work.  The vendor doesn't know how to do this and has their people use Squirrel SQL with a JDBC connection.  Since we need this setup pretty quick I install Squirrel and was able to get that connected and working. I would still prefer to use SSMS on our end for many reasons.

While I'm still trying to figure out the DB2 linked server, I was wondering if I can create a linked server using a JDBC connection since we have that working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can create a linked server using a JDBC connection since we have that working?

No.  Linked Server requires an OleDb driver.  JDBC will not work.  You'll need to download the OleDb provider from the SQL Server feature pack.  The latest one should work.  eg: [Microsoft® SQL Server® 2017 Feature Pack](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55992)

Comment: Well bummer, but thanks.  I've got the stuff from that link, back to working on it.  :)

Comment: You may want to consider using the IBM provider in the Data Server Driver Package for the [appropriate server version](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27016878).